# Triggering the return key on event unexpectedly refreshes page and gives undefined error - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, return, undefined

When I click in field, type text, and press return on keyboard it triggers the initializeTable function that refreshes page and gives error form[0] undefined.  However, when I use change event to change dropdown selection, it doesn't cause this unexpected behavior. So I'm not sure why pressing return key in text field is causing all this. Thanks for response.

```
<script>
(function($){

var listview = $('#listview');

var lists = (function(){
    var criteria = {
        dropFilter: {
            insert: function(value){
                if(value)

                    return {"filter" : value}; 
            },
            msg: "Filtering..."
        },
        searchFilter: {
            insert: function(value){
                if(value)
                    return {"search" : value}
            },
            msg: "Searching..."
        }

    }
    return { 
         create: function(component){
            var component = component.href.substring(component.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1); //sites
            return component;
        },
         setDefaults: function(component){
            var parameter = {};
            switch(component){
                case "sites":
                    parameter = {
                        'url': 'sites',                         
                        'order': 'site_num',
                        'per_page': '20'
                    }
            }
            return parameter;
        },
        getCriteria: function(criterion){
            return criteria[criterion];    

        },
        addCriteria: function(criterion, method){
            criteria[criterion] = method;   
        }
    }
})();  

var Form = function(form){
    var fields = [];
    $(form[0].elements).each(function(){  
        var field = $(this);  
        if(typeof field.attr('alter-data') !== 'undefined') fields.push(new Field(field));  
    })  
}

Form.prototype = {
    initiate: function(){
        for(field in this.fields){
            this.fields[field].calculate();  
        }
    },
     isCalculable: function(){  
        for(field in this.fields){  
                if(!this.fields[field].alterData){ 
                return false; 
            }
        } 
        return true;  
    } 
}

var Field = function(field){ 
    this.field = field;  
    this.alterData = true;  
    this.component = {'url' : window.location.hash.substring(window.location.hash.indexOf('#') + 1)};
    this.attach("change");  
    this.attach("keypress");  
}

Field.prototype = { 
    attach: function(event){
        var obj = this; //our Field object
        if(event == "change"){
            obj.field.bind("change", function(){ 
                return obj.calculate();
            })
        }
        if(event == "keypress"){
            obj.field.bind("keypress", function(e){  
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if(code == 13){ 
                    return obj.calculate();
                }
            })
        }
    },
    calculate: function(){
        var obj = this, 
            field = obj.field,  
            component = obj.component,
            msgClass = "msgClass",
            msgList = $(document.createElement("ul")).addClass("msgClass"),  
            types = field.attr("alter-data").split(" "),  
            container = field.parent(),  
            messages = [];

        field.next(".msgClass").remove();  
        for(var type in types){  
            var criterion = lists.getCriteria(types[type]);  
            if(field.val()){ 
                var result = criterion.insert(field.val()); 

                container.addClass("waitingMsg");  
                messages.push(criterion.msg);  

                obj.alterData = true;  

                initializeTable(component, result);  

            }
            else { 
                return false; 
                obj.alterData = false; 
            }
        }
        if(messages.length){
            for(msg in messages){
                msgList.append("<li>" + messages[msg] + "</li");  
            }
        }
        else{
            msgList.remove();  
        }
    }
}

$('#dashboard a').click(function(){
    var currentComponent = lists.create(this);
    var defaults = lists.setDefaults(currentComponent);
    initializeTable(defaults);
});

var initializeTable = function(defaults, custom){

    var custom = custom || {};

    var query_string = $.extend(defaults, custom);

    var params = [];
    $.each(query_string, function(key,value){
        params += key + '=' + value + "&"; 
    })
    var url = params.substring(params.indexOf("url")+4,9);
    params = params.substring(params.indexOf("&")+1).replace(params.substring(params.lastIndexOf("&")),"");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/' + url,
        data: params,
        dataType: 'html',
        error: function(){},
        beforeSend: function(){},
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(response) { 
            listview.html(response);

                var form = $('form');
                form.calculation(); 


        }
    })


}

$.extend($.fn, {   
    calculation: function(){

            var formReady = new Form($(this));

            if(!formReady.isCalculable){
                return false; 
            }

    }
})

 })(jQuery)
 </script>
```

Rather than going through whole script, the actual issue is with this:

```
if(event == "keypress"){
            obj.field.bind("keypress", function(e){ 
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if(code == 13){ 
                    return obj.calculate();
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: does your form have an onSubmit handler?

Comment: As Fosco was alluding to, the Enter key, by default, would cause the form to submit. You would need to capture this event and prevent the default behaviour

Comment: There's no onSubmit handler. I posted the entire javascript file. When the attach function is called, if the event is keypress, and if keycode is 13 (enter), then a call another function which just creates a query string. So I am in essence returning a function when when the enter key is triggered.

Comment: This is also a little trickier because I do want to execute the function that creates a query string on enter but I don't want to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it to work this this:

```
            if(event == "keypress"){
            obj.field.bind("keypress", function(e){ 
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if(code == 13){ 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return obj.calculate();
                }
            })
        }
    },
```

Hence, we first prevent default and then execute our custom function.

Comment: Not that it stops anything from working, but you might like to know that jQuery normalizes e.which, so that it can be used cross-browser.  You don't need to check e.keyCode as well.